How to verify Quartz.net port is up when set up as a hosted service
Before, in net4.8, I was able to verify quartz was up and running by pinging the port configured by the quartz.scheduler.exporter.port setting via netstat (netstat -aon) or powershell (TestConnection) but since migrating the project to net8 and configuring as a hosted service, I am no longer able to see the configured port as active. Even using TCPView does not catch it.
services.AddQuartzHostedService(q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);

It's only a guess, but will Quartz be registered under a 'health' provider, like other services?
